# How to show multiple lines instead of one?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

For school I have to do an assignment where I show the traffic length for measured times for every city. When I try to do this I get this result:

[image: Result]

Here's a photo of my dataframe:

[image: Dataframe]

Here's my code:

```
import plotly.express as px

datum = data.loc[data['Date'] == '2020-03-03']
datum = datum.sort_values(by='Time')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(datum, columns = ['City','Time', 'Date','Traffic_length', 'Traffic_jams'])

dataframe = dataframe.reset_index()

fig = px.line(dataframe, x="Time", y="Traffic_length", color='City')
fig.show()
```

I want it to show every city with a different line, like this:

[image: Example]

I tried multiple things but nothing helped. Does anyone know how to do this with plotly.express?

Comment: Some sample data in text format in the post would be helpful. @D3nic3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add and define multiple lines in a plotly time series chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59762321/how-do-i-add-and-define-multiple-lines-in-a-plotly-time-series-chart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `x` axis is categorical. You can fix it by transforming it to `datetime`. The complete code would look like:

```py
import plotly.express as px

datum = data.loc[data['Date'] == '2020-03-03']
datum = datum.sort_values(by='Time')
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(datum, columns = ['City','Time', 'Date','Traffic_length', 'Traffic_jams'])

df = dataframe.reset_index()
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]) # <-- This is what you missed

fig = px.line(df, x="Time", y="Traffic_length", color='City')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Transform data using pivot and then plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = df.pivot(index='Time', columns='City', values='Traffic_length')
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is a matplotlib answer to a plotly question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas' plot function like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = dataframe
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.groupby('City').plot(x='Time', y='Traffic_length', ax=ax, legend=True)
```

Comment: This is a matplotlib answer to a plotly question.